# Remove LUKS decrypt

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, ssd, luks

I was stupid enough to encrypt my SSD using the live ubuntu command using the command -.

sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nmp1n1

Then the system of course did not start by itself. I don't really understand how bad everything is and whether it is possible to restore it. I found a command that can remove encryption.

cryptsetup-reencrypt --decrypt /dev/nvmp1n1

But I tested it on another unnecessary partition on another disk. I encrypted and decrypted it. But this section is now unmounted. And i can't back it. I have a fear that a whole SSD disk with system data will not be able to simply decrypt again from the Live SD and use it as always. Am i right? Or is it safe to decrypt my drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nmp1n1`

If you ran this command, you didn't encrypt the existing data on the drive, **you formatted the disk** and replaced it with an encrypted volume.

If you let it run the course, then all of your data was **overwritten**.  Overwritten data is unrecoverable.

Comment: *"overwritten data is unrecoverable"* - unless you're the NSA and have $5 million to spend on forensics.